# Android Toolbar hiding doesn't work

Tags: android, android-toolbar

When I scroll `ListView` in `Fragment` my `ToolBar` doesn't hiding/showing.
I used sample from [here](https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample)
This my **xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this my **code** in `Fragment`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.home_viewpager);
    mAdapter = new HomeScreenPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.home_tabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    return view;
}
```

**Add Toolbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I can run this code, but `ToolBar` doesn't hiding. How can I hide/show it?

Comment: Post your toolbar_layout as well. Also, does the list you are trying to scroll exceed your screen size?

Comment: @Sevle added. Yes - list for test enought big (bigger than screen))

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your toolbar implementation. I can only speculate that the view that contains your fragment's listview is not supported for hidable Toolbar. (perhaps you encapsulate your Listview in a LinearLayout or a simple ScrollView?). Try to put your ListView under a NestedScrollView and check if that works. In any case, I may have more ideas if you include your fragment's layout xml.

Comment: @Sevle write as answer your idea and I accept your answer

Comment: NestedScrollView doesn't work for me either but RecyclerView seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your toolbar implementation.

A reason for the appbar_scrolling_view_behavior to not work is if there is an unsupported widget in the layout inflated by the fragment. Try to encapsulate your layout in a NestedScrollView, e.g.

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        /* Your views */
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should show us the code of `toolbar_layout`. Anyway you should add to the `toolbar` the `layout_scrollFlags` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I added code of toolBar layout. And "|snap" added too.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I solved via NestedScrollView instead ScrollView in the scrollable layout.

Comment: Hi Leonid, please see this article for how to right good answers: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)